# Kendo Tabstrip loading Grid with .Content works, .LoadContentFrom doesn't

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a tabstrip loading a grid in 2 different tabs (the same grid, the same data).

```
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")
    .Items(tabstrip =>
    {     
        tabstrip.Add().Text("Cycle Summary")
            .Content(@<text>@Html.Action("VQCycleSummary", "Sessions", new { id = Model.ID })</text>).Selected(true);
        tabstrip.Add().Text("Cycle Summary2")
            .LoadContentFrom("VQCycleSummary", "Sessions", new { id = Model.ID });


    })
)
```

The Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
  .Name("cycleGrid")
  .DataSource(ds => ds
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("VqCyclesSummary_Read", "Sessions", new {sessionId = ViewBag.SessionID}))
      .PageSize(100)
  )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.TimeStampUTC).Format("{0: MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}").Width(180);

      for (int i = 1; i <= ((int) ViewBag.MaxChannelNumber); ++i)
      {
          columns.Bound(string.Format("Channel{0}_DL", i)).Format("{0:N5}");
      }
      for (int i = 1; i <= ((int) ViewBag.MaxChannelNumber); ++i)
      {
          columns.Bound(string.Format("Channel{0}_UL", i)).Format("{0:N5}");
      }
      columns.Bound(c => c.GPS_Lat).Format("{0:N5}");
      columns.Bound(c => c.GPS_Long).Format("{0:N5}");
  })
  .Filterable()
  .Sortable()
  .Scrollable(c => c.Height(500)).Scrollable(c => c.Virtual(true)))
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult VQCycleSummary(long id)
    {
    using (var context = new Entities())
    {
        short? max = context.TestDevices.Where(td => td.SessionID == id).Max(td => td.ChannelNumber);


        ViewBag.MaxChannelNumber = max.HasValue ? (int) max + 1 : 0;
        ViewBag.SessionID = id;
        return PartialView("VqCycleSummary");
    }
}

public ActionResult VqCyclesSummary_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int sessionId)
{
    using (var context = new Entities())
    {
        var cycles = //get data

        DataSourceResult result = cycles.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

I see the data displayed properly on the first grid, but not the second. I do see the data getting returned from the controller for both grids. The columns are getting created for the second grid, but the rows of actual data aren't displaying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name your Grids in a different way. You cannot have two widgets with the same name - they are used as IDs in the markup, so the jQUery selector for the second Grid will fail

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically name grids as they are loaded?

Comment: Do it inside the cshtml view with some C# logic.